# Cancel method from inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, cancellation

I have an AsyncTask which acesses a static method in another class. This method gets files from the internet, so it has a URL Connection.
The problem is, that in certain cases I have to interrupt the AsyncTask. I can do this by setting the task to .cancel(true). But the problem is, I have to find a way to interrupt the method, the AsyncTask called in his doInBackground method.
How can I archieve that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want but it sounds like you want to cancel the Task internally in your doInBackground. you can still use `cancel(true)` to do that

Comment: It sounds to me that you want to do a .disconnect() to your URL Connection. Just listen for .cancel() on your Async and then .disconnect() the connection.

Answer (score 0):

As developer says [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
    AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not
    constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short
    operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long
    periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
    java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.
```

So It's better to use a thread instead of `Asynctask`.

When you need to stop your thread call `myThread.interrupt();`

In your thread, before each critical section check `Thread.interrupted()`;